# Function is being executed more than once

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been knocking my head over this problem for a few days now. I have a function that 
1) gets the snapshot values and then stores them into filteredLocations array
2) gets the location the user has pressed on the screen, then measures the distance between the two location points of where they pressed on the screen and the location from the snapshots
3) filters out the locations that meet the users radiusDistance and then places points on the map

The problem that I keep coming across though is with my print statements check 1 and check 2. They are being executed twice when it should only be once.

```
    func addAnnotation(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
        filteredLocations.removeAll()
        locations.removeAll()


        let sampleRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("SamplePost").child("post")

        sampleRef.observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if  let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for child in result{
                    let dictionary = child.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let lat = dictionary?["lat"] as! Double
                    let long = dictionary?["long"] as! Double
                    let image = dictionary?["image"] as! String
                    let text = dictionary?["text"] as! String
                    let user = dictionary?["user"] as! String

                    let structure = MapPoints(Latitude: lat, Longitude: long, Image: image, Text: text, User: user)
                    self.filteredLocations.append(structure)
                    self.locations.append(structure)


                    print("check one \(self.filteredLocations.count)")


                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            let refined = Double(self.radiusDistanceNumber!)


            print("check two \(self.filteredLocations.count)")



            if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began{
                self.removePointsAndClearArray()
                let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.mapView)
                let newCoordinates = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: touchPoint)
                let marker = GMSMarker(position: newCoordinates)
                marker.title = "Selected location"

                self.filteredLocations = self.locations.filter {
                    (locations) in

                    let userLocation = newCoordinates
                    let userLat = userLocation.latitude
                    let userLong = userLocation.longitude

                    let coordinateOne = CLLocation(latitude: userLat, longitude: userLong)
                    let coordinateTwo = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(locations.latitude!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(locations.longitude!))

                    let distanceFromPoints = coordinateOne.distance(from: coordinateTwo)
                    let convertToMiles = distanceFromPoints*0.00062137
                    return convertToMiles < refined
                }
                print("check three \(self.filteredLocations.count)")
                self.filteredLocations.map {
                    (location) in
                    let annotation = GMSMarker()
                    annotation.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(location.latitude!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(location.longitude!))
                    annotation.map = self.mapView
                    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: newCoordinates, zoom: 11)
                    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
                }
                print("amount that is being counted \(self.filteredLocations.count)")
                if self.filteredLocations.count <= 0 {
                    self.collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                } else{
                    self.collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                }
                print("amount before reloading collectionView \(self.filteredLocations.count)")

                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

                })
            }
        })

}
```

Comment: Print your `gestureRecognizer.state` in check one and check two, I bet you are getting two states. Probably started and ended?

Comment: Yes!!!! that was it, I moved the gestureRecognizer.state check at the beginning and it worked, thank you so much @NateBirkholz